# Combobox doesn't alow me to select item

Tags: wpf, combobox

i have the following combobox

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              Text="{Binding GroupInvoicing.AdminInvoiceBreakdownMembership}" 
                              SelectedValuePath="Tag" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=GroupInvoicing.AdminInvoiceBreakdownMembership}">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="None" Tag="N" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Level of Cover" Tag="L" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Members" Tag="M" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Payment Type" Tag="P" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Work Area" Tag="W" />
                    </ComboBox>
```

althogh the GroupInvoicing.AdminInvoiceBreakdownMembership comes back with "L" it does not select the coresponding text and doesn't let me to select anything

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModels:CompanyInvoiceConfigAdminViewModel}"
```

in viewmodel i have

```
    public GroupInvoicing GroupInvoicing
    {
        get
        {
            return this.groupInvoicing;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                this.groupInvoicing = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.GroupInvoicing);
            }
        }
    }
```

AdminInvoiceBreakdownMembership is a string

Comment: it should work fine there is no problem in your binding . Can you show more of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can't bind Text and SelectedValue to the same property. Try to remove the Text binding.